# Samba file server, copy within the server - is it coming to my local machine?

Tags: networking, samba, unc

We have a newly built SAMBA server that is hosted on AWS.  It is UNC mounted on my local machine as a network drive (S:).

When I copy something from S: to S: (i.e. internally on the server) I fear it might be going :
SAMBA -> Local machine -> SAMBA rather than SAMBA -> SAMBA

I'm consious of not using too much bandwidth and obviously this wouldn't be efficient.

Does anyone know how to check this?

Cheers,

gpc

Comment: I am not 100percent sure about that so wait for a qualified opinion: But as long as you stay inside the same drive, at least Windows Explorer doesn't copy the file to your computer. No idea about the .NET libraries though.

Comment: If you copy the file from S: to T: for example, then the file definitely ends up temporary on the client machine.